# iOS - In app purchase subscription stoped working. (FLUTTER)

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

I have an Flutter application and its in-app subscription for iOS was working fine but now all of sudden it stoped working and started giving product not found error.

[image]

My subscription is approved when I check it in App store connect.

[image]

But I found one more thing[image]

can this be the reason why it stoped working?